# control to the next statement after running eval command

Tags: bash

I have written a bash script to run a service in background and exit from the script to command line. But after running the eval command, control does not go the next statement.

```
COMMAND="nohup java -jar jenkins.war"
echo "starting service"
eval $COMMAND
echo "service running"
exit
```

echo "service running" and exit never happens. I want to run the process in the background, and return to the command prompt while the service is still running. How do I do this?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered the question and helped me! :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please, don't put a command with its arguments in a *string*. Put your command and its arguments in an *array* (and don't use upper-case variable names, that's a terribly bad practice), and **do not use `eval`**. `eval` is evil!

```
command=( nohup java -jar jenkins.war )
echo "starting service"
"${command[@]}" 2> /dev/null &
echo "service running"
```

The `&` is to have the command running in background.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I have a sub-question. Now it returns to command prompt after echoing "service running" but it displays "nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out' and does not return to command prompt until I hit ctrl+c. How can I make it go to command prompt directly without hitting ctrl+c? I dont mind saving the output to any file name but the process should not stop any time till I kill it.

Comment: @user1164061 You don't have to press Ctrl+C, just press enter. I've edited my post so that you won't have the annoying message.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf ,The same does not work for the second time while executing the script through Jenkins. Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: @Swetha: I can't help you with so little information; maybe you could open a new question where you can add all the information we need to help you solve the problem…

Answer (score 3):

Add an ampersand to the end of the call:

```
eval $COMMAND &
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
command="java -jar jenkins.war"
echo "starting service"
$command </dev/null >jenkins.out 2>jenkins.err &
echo "service running"
```

Answer (score 2):

eval doesn't solve that problem, you need the 'run-in-background' character, i.e. '&' (no quotes).

Rewrite your line as

```
 #eval $COMMAND
 $COMMAND &
```

Depending on what else you really have in $COMMAND, you may need to put the `eval` back.

Also, depending on your need, running a process in the background will generate some `jobs` output, i.e.

```
[1]     10079
```

To the std-error of your console. You need some extra syntax to redirect it to /dev/null. Here's an example:

```
COMMAND="sleep 10"
{ $COMMAND & ; } 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Using a process group (the `{ .... ; }` shouldn't cause any issues, but it might.

IHTH