# Bash Code to run an executable in a loop only when the current one has finished running

Tags: c++, bash, shell

I would  exec a bash instruction when the previous command is finished. To be clearer:

```
for i in $(seq 0 3)
do 
...elaboration
eval $command
done
```

command is a variable that contain an instruction (./binary_file flags).
In the loop command change. I would go in the next iteration of the loop when eval $command (the execution of binary file) terminated execution. Namely I would make eval $command  "blocking". How can I achieve this behavior? Or is this the default behavior?

The executed binary files by eval $command are arised from C++ source code (this could be irrilevant, I don't know). (I'm on Unix)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Comment: No, because in this moment I'm copying the project on the server that I will access in ssh (from remote ) and the .sh will run on the server when the project will be copied.

Comment: You should try it before asking here. You can substitute `sleep 10` or something for your command, to get something that takes up time so you can see how it behaves.

Comment: By default, it blocks. What issue are you facing?

Comment: Why do you use `eval` to run `$command`?

Comment: @mauro because I have to exec the content of variable command

Comment: @Umbert: `$command` will be executed as well. You need `eval` in a very few cases (like expanding variable names into variables)

Comment: I feel there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14061950/6166627).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, it blocks (with the & you permit background execution, bat without it blocks for default). However the eval is necessary else the code desn't work. Another possibility that doesn't use eval that has security problem is:

```
"${name_exe}" >"${file1_name}.txt" 2>"${file2_name}.txt"
```

(the command above in the question is

```
"${name_exe} > ${file1_name}.txt 2> ${file2_name}.txt"
```

)

Answer (score 0):

What about this (the initial dollar sign is the bash prompt):

```
$ command="who am I"
$ for i in {1..10} ; do ${command} ; done
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08 
mauro    ttys000  Jun 10 14:08
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. The eval is not necessary. I update the question, a new problem is appeared

Comment: Correction of previous one comment. Eval is necessary. Look at my answer